# Astral package error "sun remains below horizon" for Alaska in Summer

Tags: python, datetime

*I'm using the Astral package to track the sun at Anchorage Alaska and am getting the following error for the sun's position at noon summer solstice:*

**AstralError: Sun remains below the horizon on this day, at this location.**

Here is the code:

```
from astral import Astral

from pytz import timezone

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

astral = Astral()

cityName = 'Anchorage'

city = astral[cityName]

timeZone = timezone(city.timezone)

summerSolstice = datetime(2017, 6, 21, 12, 0, 0, 0, timeZone)

city.sun(date=summerSolstice, local =  True)
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Replicated your code and got this error, `AstralError: Sun never reaches 6 degrees below the horizon, at this location.`

Comment: check the geographical coordinates that `astral` is using for Anchorage

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not your code, it's with how Astral (1.3.3) is handling the `acos()` of the hour angle.

If you look at the module (`astral.py`) on line 2405 you will see that it's doing the following:

```
HA = acos(h)
```

Doing a print statement here you will see the value that is being passed into `acos()` is `-1.025435878895799`

`acos()` can only handle values from [`-1.0 <= x <= 1.0`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/number_acos.htm)